# To create a new users and roles in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic search and want to create new users in elastic search without x-pack. Is it any other plugin to create es user?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use x-pack just try out [Search Guard](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard).

Very simple to use and plus there is a docker-compose elk + search guard included.

Default username and password will be admin;admin